# Using a VeraCrypt Encrypted System Partition on a "Windows To Go" installation

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

I installed Windows To Go (Windows 10) on the system partition of a hard drive that is encrypted with VeraCrypt.

The Boot Partition is not encrypted.

I want to use this hard drive/system on many different computers.

For that reason I need the VeraCrypt bootloader on every computer to load the encrypted system.

First question:
Is it possible to use a portable hard drive with an encrypted windows system partition in many different systems?

If yes, how do I boot on the different computers with the VeraCrypt bootloader?

Comment: You are correct.  In order to use this Windows To Go instance VeraCrypt would have to already exist on the system.  TrueCrypt does not support UEFI.  I fail to see how this has anything to do with TrueCrypt.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I install the boot loader to the new system? I got veracrypt on another system, but I can´t boot from my encrpyted drive.

Comment: You would have to install VeraCrypt on each machine you want to access the Windows To Go installation.

Comment: It is installed. But it does not work. Because of the bootloader. Something is wrong with that.

Comment: It just don´t show me the passwort page. There comes the blue windows screen.

Comment: If you *un*encrypted the HDD, and then encrypted only the *data*, e.g. *Documents* and other specific folders, it should be reasonably secure and you could include VeraCrypt or TrueCrypt applications on the drive in an unencrypted folder. BTW, I've seen many complaints about being unable to recover a completely-encrypted drive if there are even minor disk errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate boot source with VeraCrypt Rescue Disk to load the boot loader from. You don't want to modify the bootloader on every computer you touch so you will want to choose the option to boot directly from the Rescue Disk.

You could use anything as the boot disk, CD\DVD, or another USB device.

> if you do not want the VeraCrypt boot loader to reside on the hard drive (for example, if you want to use an alternative boot loader/manager for other operating systems), you can boot directly from the VeraCrypt Rescue Disk (as it contains the VeraCrypt boot loader too) without restoring the boot loader to the hard drive. Just insert your Rescue Disk into your CD/DVD drive and then enter your password in the Rescue Disk screen.

**SOURCE:**
https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/VeraCrypt%20Rescue%20Disk.html

Comment: Do I need the rescue disk every time? How does windows recognize, before it boots to normal system, that I want to boot the encrpyted hard drive?

Comment: Windows doesn't select the boot device. The BIOS or UEFI does. Read this: https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/comment-page-1/